# jQuery Page Scroll every time Down when Key press Down in single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Want page scroll down every time when i press key down from key board i want page scroll down to next something pixcel fixed each time

anyone please help me how to do it

I Want Continue Scroll on every key press at the last div

```
http://jsfiddle.net/dhaval17/etfYz/
```

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dhaval17/etfYz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple.

1. Register for keydown events.
2. Find out where you are.
3. Decide where you should go, based on where you are.
4. Go there.

Tadah!

*[edit]*

This js function does work for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 40) { 
           $($(".scrollToMe").get().reverse()).each(function(i, div) {
               var top = $(this).offset().top;
               if (top - $(document).scrollTop() <= 0) {
                    var next = $(this).next(".scrollToMe");
                    if (next) {
                      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).next(".scrollToMe").offset().top }, 'slow');                  
                    }
                    return false;
               }
           });
       }
  });
});
```

You were always trying to scroll to ALL/ANY div(s) at arrow keydown, although you needed to check the point 2 from my list above (where you are). And then point 3, decide where to go, which in your simple case is the `.next()` div based on the one currently at top.

Comment: I am not such a brilliant can you provide me an example please ?

Comment: Well, since your question (at least before you provided your jsfiddle link) was really unclear, you cannot expect anything else than an unclear answer.

Comment: your answer is ok but it works only single time key press when i press key again to move down page it doesn't work

Comment: Really? It does work for me. Keydown #1, scrolls down to green div. Keydown #2, scrolls down to blue div. Keydown #3, scrolls down to yellow div.

Could you update your jsfiddle with the new code, and let me see what's wrong..?

Comment: Change $(window).load into $(document).ready, and it works for me.

Comment: see again above link i have try to document ready but still doesn't work

Comment: Okay, found some errors. First of all, your page contained some others divs (window-resizer-tooltip for instance), that I never took into account. Those made the whole thing break. In order to only navigate to the colored divs, I added a class to them (.scrollToMe). Check out the updated code in my answer. Also look into my own test of this at http://www.stafffan.se/stackoverflow19131554/ if you need more reference.

Comment: So it seems. Have to look into that later.

Comment: Seems like FF didn't understand $("body").scrollTop(). Changing it to $(document).scrollTop() did the trick though.

Also verified in IE 7-10.

Comment: When it is at the top of page or at the bottom of page and we press key from keyboard it's returns JavaScript error